# How to make API calls to AWS Lambda using API Reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda

I want to handle (create, delete, invoke, list down, update) AWS Lambda functions using REST API calls. I don't have intentions to use AWS console or AWS CLI. Some content in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Reference.html) is unclear to me. I want to know the following things.

- Base path or Host path for the API calls
- Example request for invoking a lambda function

Answer (score 0):

1. Base path for API calls will be in this format:
   `https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

   So the full path will be
   `https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/FunctionName/invocations?Qualifier=Qualifier`
   where the definition for **FunctionName** and **Qualifier** can be
   found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html).
2. You need to sign the HTTP request using **Signature Version 4** with
   valid AWS IAM credentials before sending it. The signing process can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). Example code for the signing process using Python is given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html). Then follow instructions in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) to make the invocation request.